# ExpandableObjectConverter properties are not showing in propertyGrid c#

Tags: c#, propertygrid, typeconverter

I have created basic class with ExpandableObjectConverter type and it contain properties that I need to show as expandable in the calling class to be shown in the propertyGrid but it only shows the class name in the property grid without the properties under it

```
 [TypeConverter(typeof(System.ComponentModel.ExpandableObjectConverter))]
public class SR1000
{

    [Description("Recieve Data Timeout")]
    public int Timeout { get; set; }

    [Description("Client IP Address")]
    [DisplayName("IP Address")]
    public string IpAddress { get; set; }

    [Description("Command and Data Port")]
    public int Port { get; set; }

    [Description("Bar Code Reader Postion")]
    public Point2D Poistion { get; set; }
 }


 [Serializable()]
[XmlRoot("BarCodeReader.BarCodeReader")]
public class BarCodeReader : ISystemDevice, IStationSpecificDevice
{

    [Category("SR1000")]
    public SR1000 SR1000 { get; set; }
}
```

Any Idea what I'm missing

Answer (score 3):

I totally forgot to create an instance of the property object

```
 public BarCodeReader()
    {
        SR1000 = new SR1000();
    }
```